# EF Core 2.1.0 set default string length and column type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Since Entity Framework uses `nvarchar(max)` as default for strings I would like to set something else as default.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48408/ef-code-first-uses-nvarcharmax-for-all-strings-will-this-hurt-query-performan

In Entity Framework 6.1.3 I could modify `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` like this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasPrecision(0));

modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
    .Configure(s => s.HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnType("nvarchar"));
```

If I then modified a property with data annotations EF used these values instead, like this:

```
[MaxLength(128)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
[MaxLength]
public string Comment { get; set; }
```

However using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0` I cant do it like this and I can't use `Conventions` either.

I could solve `datetime` like this but if I try to do the same for strings the migration says `type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 128` if I use data annotations for example. How can I solve this?

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime)))
{
    property.Relational().ColumnType = "datetime2(0)";
}
```

Comment: Why putting differtent size in nvarchar and maxlength?

Comment: @CodeNotFound That is the problem, the migration generates code like this in EF core: `Comment = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 128, nullable: false),`. This did not happen in EF 6.1.3.

Comment: By the way, I don't know why you don't just use nvarchar(128) instead of nvarchar(MAX)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 6.0+):**

The ability to specify different type mapping defaults finally has been added in EF Core 6.0 via the so called [Pre-convention model configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#pre-convention-model-configuration), so the code now would be something like this:

```cs
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);

    configurationBuilder.Properties<string>()
        //.AreUnicode(false)
        //.AreFixedLength()
        .HaveMaxLength(256);
}
```

More examples are provided in the documentation link.

**Important Note:** However, as mentioned by @PeterB in comments and verified in EF Core issue tracker, for some reason this configuration has higher precedence (same as model builder fluent API), so you won't be able to override these "defaults" with data annotations (fluent configuration in `OnModelCreating` will still do). So you might need to use the original approach below in case you rely on data annotations for overriding defaults.

**Original:**

There are several attributes indirectly affecting the column type of a `string` property - `MaxLength` (e.g. `varchar(256)` vs `varchar(MAX)`, `IsUnicode` (e.g. `nvarchar` vs `varchar`) and `IsFixedLength` (e.g. `char` vs `varchar`).

The current model API is inconsistent. The first is accessible through [`GetMaxLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.propertyextensions.getmaxlength?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_PropertyExtensions_GetMaxLength_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IProperty_) and [`SetMaxLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.mutablepropertyextensions.setmaxlength?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_MutablePropertyExtensions_SetMaxLength_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableProperty_System_Nullable_System_Int32__), the second - via [`IsUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.propertyextensions.isunicode?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_PropertyExtensions_IsUnicode_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IProperty_) and [`IsUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.mutablepropertyextensions.isunicode?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_MutablePropertyExtensions_IsUnicode_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableProperty_System_Nullable_System_Boolean__), and there is no public model API for the third one (only fluent API).

So to set the `MaxLength` you could use:

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
{
    if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
        property.SetMaxLength(256);
}
```

which is not fully correct, because `null` in this case has dual meaning - not specified and `MAX`.

The correct way requires using EF Core internal API, which provides much more configuration methods, in particular allowing you to pass [`ConfigurationSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.configurationsource?view=efcore-2.1) enum value along with the attribute value. `ConfigurationSource` enum values define the priority of the configuration - with `Convention` being the lowest, then `DataAnnotation` and finally `Explicit` being the highest. The whole idea is that the lower priority configuration do not overwrite the configuration already set by a higher priority. All public fluent API use `Explcit`, while in our case the `Convention` perfectly fits (since we are simulating conventional default).

So if you accept the warning *"This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases."*, add

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
```

and use

```
foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
    .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
{
    ((Property)property).Builder
        .HasMaxLength(256, ConfigurationSource.Convention);
}
```

Comment: May I enquire if there has been any update on this answer, this does indeed work but as it's an internal method it may not be supported in future updates so is there any better approach one should use instead?

Comment: @StevenPrice When it changes, or better when EF Core exposes publicly  conventions, then the answer will be updated. Currently even the latest EFC 5.x does not provide public API for such tasks. There is public `IConventionPropertyBuilder` interface, but no public way to get it, as `PropertyBuilder` class (which implements it) constructor is also marked as "internal API".

Comment: @IvanStoev Really good answer as always. A clarification for anyone that finds this is that the `DbContext` needs a `DbSet` for this to work like `public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }`. You will get `type: "nvarchar(max)` instead of `type: "nvarchar(256)` otherwise.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just upgraded to NuGet `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0` and then `AsProperty` does not work anymore. `'IMutableProperty' does not contain a definition for 'AsProperty' and no accessible extension method 'AsProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableProperty' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. What is the correct way using .NET 6?

Comment: @Ogglas But of course, they can't miss the opportunity to break some "internal" (or even public) API :( The good thing is that they added (finally!) a better alternative. Answer updated (also the original code to use cast instead of the removed extension method which was doing exactly the same thing).

Comment: @IvanStoev Haha of course not! Thank you for the new example and documentation link!

Comment: Pre-convention model configuration breaks `StringLength` and `MaxLength` attributes. The lecagy solution works as expected.

Comment: @PeterB Quite annoying if true (haven't checked), because by idea conventions must be with less priority than attributes and explicit fluent configuration.

Comment: @IvanStoev: That is what I thought, but [the experts state otherwise](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28541#issuecomment-1198992230) :-(