# Entity Framework Core: General model configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

When configuring my model mappings in EF Core, I want to set some general mapping rules, eg. tell every class having `Id` property that this property gets mapped to DB column `ID`.

Using Entity Framework, I was able to achieve this using this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<IEntity<long>>().Configure(c =>
    {
        c.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
    });
}
```

(`IEntity<long>` is a simple interface having only single property `long Id { get; set; }`. Every entity class in my model simply implements this interface.)

Is anything similar possible also with Entity Framework Core 2.2+?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275567/how-to-apply-common-configuration-to-all-entities-in-ef-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I ended up with this solution:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (IMutableEntityType mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        bool isEntity = mutableEntityType.ClrType.GetInterface($"{nameof(IEntity<int>)}`1") != null;
        if (isEntity)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(mutableEntityType.ClrType).Property(nameof(IEntity<int>.Id)).HasColumnName("ID");
        }
    }
}
```