# Change property defaults

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In EntityFramework 6 I could do something like the following to change the defaults for a particular data type:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(
   DbModelBuilder mb
) {
   mb
   .Properties<DateTime>()
   .Configure(config => 
      config
      .HasColumnType("datetime2")
      .HasPrecision(7)
   );
```

This saves having to specify these details for every single `DateTime` property in the DB.

Is there an equivalent way of changing property defaults in EF Core? There is no such `Properties` member on the EF Core `ModelBuilder` type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50852517/43846

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension method for this.

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Properties<TPropertyType>(
        this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
        Action<IMutableProperty> configureAction
    )
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(entityType => entityType.GetProperties())
            .Where(entityProperty => typeof(TPropertyType) == entityProperty.ClrType)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(configureAction);
    }
}
```

Then I can do something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTimeOffset>(
        property =>
        {
            if (property.Name == nameof(Entity.CreatedAtUtc))
            {
                property.SetDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Which seems to be not needed since [EF Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#pre-convention-model-configuration)