# Set global collation for SQLite in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, collation

SQLite is case sensitive by default so I need to set the `NOCASE` collation using Entity Framework Core.

I know I can set it per column like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .Property(t => t.MyProperty)
                .HasColumnType("TEXT COLLATE NOCASE");
}
```

But I need it for just about every text column in the database.

Is there a way I can set this collation to all text columns without having to manually go through each and every one?

I've tried `modelBuilder.UseCollation("NOCASE");`, but this has no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core 2.1.0 set default string length and column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840730/ef-core-2-1-0-set-default-string-length-and-column-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Could you [submit an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose) for it?

You can work around it by overriding `ConfigureConventions` in your DbContext:

```csharp
protected override void ConfigureConventions(
    ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder.Properties<string>().UseCollation("NOCASE");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Reported at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32051